# How Can I Fix My Resolution After Installing Nvidia Drivers?

Tags: nvidia, resolution, nvidia-driver

I have a GTX-1060 3gb graphics card and installed the nvidia-440 drivers through the terminal. After updating elementary the resolution became smaller and I could not change it back to 1920x1080. I checked the nvidia x server settings but the application was completely blank. The default nouveau video driver gives me 1080p but I need to use the nvidia drivers. I blacklisted the nouveau drivers because they were causing crashes. I have tried uninstalling the nvidia drivers and then reinstalling. I have checked the additional drivers application and it said I was using the 440 drivers. What can I do to set my monitor to 1080p?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I recommend you is to use the proprietary nvidia drivers. The best way to do it is in recovery mode with network enabled or into tty console screen.

a. The first option **recovery mode** can be entered by choosing **advanced options for elementary os** from grub menu, then on the next screen the top option with [recovery] in its name. When it boots, from the menu there fisrt select **enable network** and then go to the **root shell**. Execute first `apt update` and if there are no connection errors, you can proceed with the numbered instructions below. You can omit `sudo` in the lines in recovery mode, because you are using the root shell.

b. You can access the **tty screen** once you are into pantheon greeter, but instead of typing your username/password into the boxes there you have to press <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> (f1 - f6 will work) and then login into console mode.

Continue with the below commands **only** if you have working network - the easiest way to check this is by `sudo apt update` - if you have no network errors, you can continue.

## 1. remove all nvidia drivers previously installed

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
```

if you do not have the `purge` command you can install it by `sudo apt install purge`.

## 2. Add the graphics-drivers team repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

Confirm adding it and the system should automaticaly execute `apt update`, if not - you have to execute it by typing `sudo apt update`

## 3. (optional) view a list of all drivers with the recommended one

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

## 4.install automatically the recommended version

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

You can add comments if you have problems with this, and if it works for you, please accept this answer.